# restless neck while doing exercise

Tags: gym, physical-therapy

When I exercise I feel a lot of strain in my neck even with very low weight. Specifically while exercising for chest, biceps and mainly shoulder. Without any intention I seem to be straining my neck.
What is the reason for this, what causes the stress to my neck?

Comment: Do you experience this during or after exercise? Can you be a bit more specific about the exercises, which exercises specifically and for how long have you been doing them? What are very low weights?

Comment: Also, details on exactly when. Such as "When doing a bench press and lowering/raising the weight I get a strain along the left/right/back/front of my neck".

Answer (score 1):

I think a lot of people unconsciously stress their necks during exercises *(especially weightlifting)*. 
 
It takes practice to relax the neck during these exercises. 
 
If possible, exercise in front of a mirror and you'll see that your neck is being unconsciously stretched when lifting. 
 
Fix the issue by consciously relaxing your neck once you realize it's being stretched. 
 
After some time, you'll be able to lift without stretching your neck.

Comment: Did you mean neck is being stressed rather than stretched.  I agree with some people weightlifting can carry a lot of tension in their neck

Comment: @Tracyat2bactive The stress comes from *unconsciously stretching the neck* in a forward movement or *constricting it* as if trying to shrink it.Either action creates an undue stress on the neck. That's why some instructors emphasize *relaxing the neck* .

Comment: Wouldn't "packing" the neck be more appropriate?  I.e. keeps the neck in a neutral position and maintains the tightness required during most exercises.

Comment: @BerinLoritsch I don't know what *packing* meant, so I googled it. The images I saw seemed like those people put pressure on their necks. Yes, the neck should be in a neutral position and the required tightness should be maintained. Isn't that *resting the neck*?

Comment: http://www.t-nation.com/free_online_article/most_recent/much_ado_about_deadlifting

Comment: http://charlieweingroff.com/2010/11/packing-in-the-neck/

Comment: @BerinLoritsch You're right. *Packing* should be the proper neck position. I read the articles you listed; also, as the weight being lifted increases, it's increasingly impossible for the neck to remain in a neutral position without any tension int it. Thanks for the link.